# Is it possible to bind a policy to a Group in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I'm trying to add a behaviour to all users in a group (i.e. add an aspect to user if added and removed when not in group) however I get an exception at the point of binding within the init method:

```
public void init() {
    this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(OnUpdateNodePolicy.QNAME, ContentModel.TYPE_AUTHORITY_CONTAINER, new JavaBehaviour(this, "onUpdateNode"));
    this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(BeforeUpdateNodePolicy.QNAME, ContentModel.TYPE_AUTHORITY_CONTAINER, new JavaBehaviour(this, "beforeUpdateNode"));
}
```

Any other way I can get around this if this isn't possible?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: A Null pointer exception on the first policy component bind line.

Comment: So if you change it to contentModel.Type_content or something it works?

Comment: I guess you forgot to inject policComponent and that's why you see the NPE.

Comment: @AndreasSteffan Yeah. I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to act on users as they are added and removed from a group, you should be using the ChildAssociation policies.  Have a look at http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/policy/AssociationPolicy.html to pick the ones which apply for you.

That said, it may be smarter to just extend AuthorityService and wrap calls to

```
public void addAuthority(String parentName, String childName);
public void removeAuthority(String parentName, String childName);
```

adding your custom logic.

Comment: At first I though the policy component was being ignored but I realised I hadn't changed bound it to the right association. but after I did. I get an exception that "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}member has not been defined in the data dictionary"

Comment: Aahh nevermind, I should be binding to association behaviours.

Comment: Thats most likely because the dictionary has not been bootstrapped at the time your init-method kicks in. In my apps, I do not need it for some reason, but you might want to try depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap" on your bean. If things still go wrong, show your bean def along with the path of the context file.